# C# Check if directory or file?

Tags: c#, file, directory

I've tried

```
if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
    //is directory
else
    //is file
```

but this doesn't always work. not sure why.
Any ideas?

Comment: what contains the path variable yor are checking for?

Comment: How have you come to the conlcusion that 'this doesn't always work'. Is an error/exception raised?

Answer (score 2):

Both [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) and [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) will return false if an error occurs during the check, or if the user does not have sufficient permissions.

From the docs at [Directory.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx)

> If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory,
>   the Exists method will return false. The Exists method returns false
>   if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file
>   exists.

From the docs at [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the
>   specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false
>   regardless of the existence of path...
>   The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to
>   determine if the specified file exists.